# Can't move only one object

Tags: python, opengl

i'm trying to programming basic movements for the cubes in my scene, but the point is that i just achieve move all the cubes or nones, i don't know where is exactly the fail, i tried do a glTranslate(self.x, self.y, 0.0) before drawing the cube and in the main i want change the 'x' and 'y' positions.

```py
class rect:
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, c):
        self.xp=x
        self.yp=y
        if color == 0:
            glColor3f(0,1.0,0)    
        else:
            glColor3f(1.0,0,0)

        glPushMatrix()
        glTranslatef(self.xp, self.yp, 0.0)
        glBegin(GL_QUADS)                                  # start drawing a rectangle
        glVertex2f(self.xp, self.yp)                                   # bottom left point
        glVertex2f(self.xp + width, self.yp)                           # bottom right point
        glVertex2f(self.xp + width, self.yp + height)                  # top right point
        glVertex2f(self.xp, self.yp + height)                          # top left point
        glEnd()
        glPopMatrix()
        glFlush()

    def move(self):
        self.xp = self.xp + 1

def main():

    pygame.init()
    display = (1920,1080)
    pygame.display.set_mode(display, DOUBLEBUF|OPENGL)

    gluPerspective(45, (display[0]/display[1]), 1.0, 50.0)

    glTranslatef(0.0,0.0, -5)

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        c = cube(0, 0, 1, 1, 0)
        c.move()
        pygame.display.flip()
        pygame.time.wait(10)

main()
```

Comment: You only seem to change the value of the `self.xp` without redrawing the vertices. The position of the vertices is set in the initialization. Changing `self.xp` afterwards won't change their position. You'll have to change the coordinates of the vertices if you want them to move.

Comment: Hi Martin, thank you for answered, i still having problems, because if i try to redraw the square i create a new one and also my  move method doesn't change the value of xp (i checked it with a print). Maybe would be better create the vertex of the square as a member variables of the class?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't help you, there. I don't use GL, myself, but tkinter Canvas to draw moving things. There, I know the methods to change the properties of an element. In GL, I don't know any functions.

Comment: @GonzaloMedinaMedina In your example, there is just 1 cube. Even worse the cube is instantiated in the while loop (see [Instance Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#instance-objects)).

Comment: i could get a solution to move only one of the cubes:

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution (the cubes representate animals so that's the reason because i have a rabbit class :D )

```
class rabbit:

def __init__(self, s, i, g, x, y, n, c):
    self.xp=x
    self.yp=y
    self.number =  n
    self.speed = s
    self.intelligence = i
    self.gender = SEXS[g]
    
def move(self):
    self.xp = self.xp + 0.001
   

def draw(self, x, y, w, h, c):
    if c == 0:
       glColor3f(0,1.0,0)    
    elif c == 1:
       glColor3f(1.0,0,0)
    
    glPushMatrix()
    glTranslatef(self.xp, self.yp, 0.0)
    glBegin(GL_QUADS)                                 # start drawing a rectangle       
    glVertex2f(self.xp, self.yp)                                   # bottom left point
    glVertex2f(self.xp + w, self.yp)                           # bottom right point
    glVertex2f(self.xp + w, self.yp + h)                  # top right point
    glVertex2f(self.xp, self.yp + h)
    glEnd()
    glFlush()
    glPopMatrix()

def main():
n_rabbits=0

pygame.init()
display = (1920,1080)
pygame.display.set_mode(display, DOUBLEBUF|OPENGL)

gluPerspective(45, (display[0]/display[1]), 1.0, 50.0)

glTranslatef(0.0,0.0, -5)

rabbits_lists=[]

rabbits_drew=False

g = random.randint(0,1)
s = random.randint(0,10)
i = random.randint(0,10)
x = random.randint(0,300)
y = random.randint(0,300)

n_rabbits = n_rabbits+1
r1 = rabbit(s, i, g, 0.1, 0.1, n_rabbits, 1)

n_rabbits = n_rabbits+1
r = rabbit(s, i, g, 0, 0, n_rabbits, 0)


while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

    r.draw(r.xp, r.yp, 0.1, 0.1, 1)
    r.move()

    r1.draw(r1.xp, r1.yp, 0.1, 0.1, 0)
    
    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.time.wait(10)


    main()
```